# Do inline style tags block rendering?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

You should inline critical path css, like  for better performance, but what about a whole inline style section?

'css blocks rendering, place your style sheets in the head' but is that just for requests? Does the browser read the whole page and stop for some reason when it gets to inline css?

Comment: I think that "css blocks rendering" means that while file is being downloaded, request, browser just waits. Not sure if inline or any css for that "blocks rendering"

Comment: It stops when it gets to inline CSS to parse it, but not for nearly as long as a request. Also, when it’s recommended to ”inline critical path CSS”, a `<style>` block is exactly what’s meant; using the `style` attribute is *always* a bad idea.